# PHPUnit instllation broken since Mountain Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, configuration, phpunit, runtime-error

I upgraded my Mac from Lion to Mountain Lion a few months ago.

I previously had PHPUnit working with my Zend Framework 1.11 without issue but had not used it much.

I now have Zend Framewoprk 2 running on a Quick Start website but I simply cannot gwet PHPUnit to work.

I've searched numerous questions related to this on Stackoverflow and tried reinstalls and path changes to php.ini without success.

I have also checked that my PEAR install is working fine, which it is but the error is the same when I try "phpunit --version"

```
PHP Warning:  require(/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 43

Warning: require(/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 43
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear/PEAR:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear:/usr/bin/phpunit:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit:/usr/bin/phpunit:/Users/johnadmin/pear/bin/pear') in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 43

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear/PEAR:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear:/usr/bin/phpunit:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit:/usr/bin/phpunit:/Users/johnadmin/pear/bin/pear') in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 43
```

Attempts to reinstall phpunit results in me been told phpunit is already installed and its version current.

```
$ sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
phpunit/PHPUnit is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.7.10
install failed
```

Trying to uninstall fails as phpunit is a dependancy in other items/applications.

Is there anyway I can fix this or completely remove it and reinstall fresh?

include_path in my php.ini is:

```
include_path=".:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear/PEAR:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear:/usr/bin/phpunit:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit:/usr/bin/phpunit:/Users/johnadmin/pear/bin/pear"
```

Additional info in case its relevant:

```
> which phpunit
/usr/bin/phpunit

> which pear
/Users/johnadmin/pear/bin/pear

> which php
/usr/bin/php
```

Autoload.php is located in

```
/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit
```

Additionally, the folder '/usr/lib/php/' exists but the PHPUnit directory is not under that, it is under **/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit**

bash_profile content/paths

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/imagick/3.0.1:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear:$

##
# Your previous /Users/johnadmin/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/johnadmin/.bash_$
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-04-17_at_08:37:29: adding an appropriate PATH variable$
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/johnadmin/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/johnadmin/.bash_$
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-10-09_at_16:09:32: adding an appropriate PATH variable$
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/johnadmin/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/johnadmin/.bash_$
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-12-06_at_13:40:25: adding an appropriate PATH variable$
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

At my wits end as I do not know what else to check frankly and any help would be a big help. Ta
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind after hours of trying various solutions I found that creating a simlink to the PHPUnit folder worked.

Command I used was

```
sudo ln -s /Users/johnadmin/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, this helped me a lot:

1. Install Composer ([http://getcomposer.org](http://getcomposer.com))
2. `composer require phpunit/phpunit 3.7.*`
3. `composer update`

Three simple steps to pull PHPUnit source, **and binary** to your project.

Comment: I used pear for installing phpunit, phpunit installed fine but my problem was a error with paths but solved it with a symlink, added my own answer below. Cheers for the help though just glad the symlink fixed everything and its working fine now.